# How to change height of search bar? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I have this:

http://postimg.cc/image/oepn8hhzd/

and I need this one:

http://postimg.cc/image/4bacislw5/

My code of search bar

```
var searchBar:UISearchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 0))


    searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    self.searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    self.searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    self.searchBar.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    self.searchBar.clipsToBounds = true
    searchBar.placeholder = "Search for cities"
    searchBar.sizeToFit()


    self.searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "Search@3x"), forSearchBarIcon: UISearchBarIcon.Search, state: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "Close@3x"), forSearchBarIcon: UISearchBarIcon.Clear, state: UIControlState.Normal)

    searchBar.delegate = self


    var leftNavBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: searchBar)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftNavBarButton
```

Any ideas?
(Sorry for links, I cannot insert images)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use another view as navigation bar title and place search bar inside it.

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 44)
let titleView = UIView(frame: frame)
searchController.searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
searchController.searchBar.frame = frame
titleView.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
navigationItem.titleView = titleView
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: It works but when you set border to it then the output doesn't meet the expected output. please check it.

Comment: Its works, but i has same output like I already have, but its placed int title. I have to create space between color line and search bars border. Any other idea?

Comment: Nop I think that is the only way if you set it with title.

Comment: Like I said, place it in title gives me no advantages. If I am possible to create that space, its ok, but that title works same like my left button.

Comment: Thanks, but in order to get a full-width change 100 to UIScreen.main.bounds.width
'let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 44)'