# How to change height of the searchBar in UISearchController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying out a design that uses a searchController and a tableView. The searchBar is set to the tableView's table header. My problem is I can't properly set the height of the searchBar.

I tried to directly set the height of the searchBar, which turns to only change the the textField's height rather than the searchBar itself. Additionally, if you look at the gif below, the searchBar in searching status is mis-positioned under the safe area in this way.

[image]

So, in summary, how to properly set the height of the searchBar?

Comment: Please share the relevant code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31446458/how-to-change-height-of-search-bar-swift check this

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solve?